# How to return a file in django

Tags: python, django, express, templates

I have a django app through which I would like to serve an index.html file. This html file isn't in default django template, rather I have the index.html in a react build folder. I don't want to render the template, rather I want to send it. The render method isn't working, and I don't know if there is any django method that can serve the file. What I want to accomplish can be done using `res.sendFile()` in expressjs.

```
def home(request):
    return FileResponse(request, 'home/home.html')
```

The FileResponse method isn't working here.

Comment: https://zetcode.com/django/fileresponse/

Comment: Same question here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50479804/how-to-send-file-to-response-in-django

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can try this, you can use it specifically for CSV, but if you want in Djagngo's guide you can see the example for PDF [Link](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/howto/outputting-csv/)

Comment: Thanks @John Bull. However, It's not csv file I want to serve. I want django equivalent of `res.sendFile()` found in expressjs

Comment: Try: the_file = open("somefile.txt", "wb", buffering=False)
response = json(the_file)

Answer (score 0):

[FileResponse](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/request-response/#fileresponse-objects) has a single required argument, an open file-like object.

This means you should not provide `request` to it. On the other hand, you need to `open()` the file yourself (preferably in binary mode) instead of just providing its path.

```py
def home(request):
    return FileResponse(open('home/home.html', 'rb'))
```